# Modify list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, insert

I have `s = [{'A':10}]`. I did `s[0].insert(s[0])`, so that `s: [{'A':10}, {'A':10}]`. When I modify `s[0]['B'] = 20`, my desired s is `[{'A':10, 'B':20}, {'A':10}]`. However, I got s: `[{'A':10, 'B':20}, {'A':10}, {'B':20}]`. Could someone please help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a dictionary is a reference data type, you only insert another reference to the same dictionary when doing

```
s[0].insert(s[0])
```

You can avoid that by making a deep copy which can be done easily by the module copy:

```
import copy
s[0].insert(copy.deepcopy(s[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory problem. When you make a copy of A it point's to the same memory location as the original A so any changes to A changes both. You need to do a deepcopy which will put the copy of A in it's on memory location. Here is a link that explains a bit better [deepcopy](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_deep_copy.php)

```
from copy import deepcopy
s[0].insert(deepcopy(s[0]))
```